# Why does my program keep on giving me heap buffer overflow even though I am not going out of bounds on my array or overwriting any values

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am trying to solve Leetcode problem 746 which is a basic Dynamic programming problem. Even though my logic is little complex, it should work perfectly fine. I have had 2 sleepless nights trying to find what the problem in my code is. Can someone point exactly where am I doing heap overflow and how to avoid it ?

Also, I forgot to add, the size of cost is always greater than 3.

I have already tried inserting comments into my solution. I have realized that the problem lies with the costing[1] updating code but what the problem is, I have no idea.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minCostClimbingStairs(vector<int>& cost) {
        if(cost.size() < 3)
            return 0;

        int costing[2];
        costing[0]=cost[0];
        costing[1]=cost[1];
        int i=1;
        while(i<cost.size()-2)
        {
                if(costing[0]+cost[i]>costing[0]+cost[i+1])
                {
                    costing[0]=costing[0]+cost[i+1];
                    i++;
                }

                else if (costing[0]+cost[i]<=costing[0]+cost[i+1])
                {
                    costing[0]=costing[0]+cost[i];
                    i+=2;
                }

                if(costing[1]+cost[i+1]>=costing[1]+cost[i+2])
                {
                    cout<<costing[1]+cost[i+1]<<"is greater than " <<costing[1]+cost[i+2]<<"\n";
                    costing[1]+=cost[i+2];
                    i+=2;
                }

                else if (costing[1]+cost[i+1]<costing[1]+cost[i+2])
                {
                                    cout<<costing[1]+cost[i+1]<<"is less than " <<costing[1]+cost[i+2]<<"\n";

                costing[1]+=cost[i+1];
                    i++;
                }
        }

        return min(costing[0],costing[1]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Just edited the question. Size of cost is always greater than 3.

Comment: Did you try to output some values of of `i` as the program runs? It seems to me that the error does not occur right at start.

Comment: If `i` is incremented in the first `if()` or `else if()` the second `if()` or `else if()` could access out-of-bound in edge case.

Comment: @Wolf Yes. It runs for half part perfectly fine and then stops running and gives me address Sanitizer error.

Comment: @Scheff But shouldn't I get an out of bound exception in that case. 
I am getting 
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x604000000078 at pc 0x0000004057fa bp 0x7ffd21358450 sp 0x7ffd21358448
error.

Comment: May be, it's a good idea to put `assert()`s into your code at any place where you believe to know what value `i` can have or not have.

Comment: On one hand, you might be right. On the other hand, if your program does something unreliable I wouldn't expect any definite behavior. ;-)

Comment: @Sma No, you won’t get exceptions. Some runtimes range-check vector indexing in debug builds, but not arrays. If you want checks, use vectors and its `at` function instead of indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial value of `i` is 1. It can increment by 4 in one iteration of the `while` under different conditions (if the first `else if` and the second `if` are true).

So in the second iteration of the `while`, the value of `i` can become 9.

So in the last `else if`,  `cost[i+2]` is `cost[11]`. Since your dataset has only 10 elements (as mentioned in the comment), this results in an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: You sir deserve a cookie. Thanks a lot for your input. Yes. I realized that potentially what you said can happen. I am still not sure how should I change my code as having different while loops for both logics seems to be too much of code. But atleast now I know what the issue is. 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: thanks for helping me understand that *heap overflow* is not the same as *not enough memory* i.e. [std::bad_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be that your heap has not enough space? Vector allocate continuous memory blocks on the heap. If a vector grows for a long time, the heap may get fragmented. So at some point there is no free block available.

Maybe using [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) can help you prevent this behaviour.

Also keep in mind that the indexed access ([`[i]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)) to vectors doesn't include range checking as opposed to the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) function.